# How to find the type of type hint from a given a python variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

```
import websockets
from typing import get_type_hints

>>> web: websockets.WebSocketClientProtocol = None
>>> web = websockets.connect("wss://some_website")
>>> type(web)
<class 'websockets.legacy.client.Connect'>

>>> get_type_hints(web)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/typing.py", line 1255, in get_type_hints
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a module, class, method, '
TypeError: <websockets.legacy.client.Connect object at 0x7fb732408760> is not a module, class, method, or function.

>>> get_type_hints(websockets.connect)
{}
```

If I don't know that the type hint of the variable `web` is `websockets.WebSocketClientProtocol`, is there a way that I can query the type hint from it?

Updated based on wjandrea:

```
>>> import websockets
>>> from typing import get_type_hints
>>> web: websockets.WebSocketClientProtocol = None
>>> web = websockets.connect("wss://some_website")
>>> from __future__ import annotations    # this is NOT necessary
>>> __annotations__['web']
<class 'websockets.legacy.client.WebSocketClientProtocol'>
```

Comment: Off-topic, but "from a given a python variable" is not grammatical. You might mean "from a given python variable" or "given a python variable". I'd fix it myself, but to me the connotations are different.

Comment: Are you looking for `__annotations__['web']`?

Comment: @wjandrea, I just want to know how to get the type hint if I don't know it. Thx

Comment: >>> __annotations__['web']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'web'

Comment: I have no idea why you'd get that `KeyError`. You might be doing something wrong

Comment: @wjandrea, now I can get `websockets.legacy.client.WebSocketClientProtocol`

Comment: Please don't put a solution in the question. Instead, post an answer (yes, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer)).

Comment: Why are you doing `from __future__ import annotations` late? `web`'s annotation has already been evaluated at that point.